# mod_wsgi compiled in python 2.7.3 and runtime in python 2.7.4

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get my Apache server to run mod_wsgi and am getting this error:

```
[Fri Jul 19 10:24:05 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.3.
[Fri Jul 19 10:24:05 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.4.
```

Is this fixed by going into `/usr/local/src` where Python is located and running:

```
./configure --enable-shared
make install
```

What I have read so far seems like the fix needs to be that mod_wsgi has to have access to all Python libraries, and thus running the `--enable-shared` command will allow it to work.  After i see the above `[warn]` lines in my Apache error.log, it then says that it can't look up environmental variables in my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` `settings.py` file.  When I replace those variables, it then says that it can look up other Python packages in other places.

I am running Ubuntu Linux 13.04 on a Rackspace VPS, Using Django 1.5.2 and on my local machine have Python 2.7.3 but the native Python to the Rackspace VPS is 2.7.4.  The mod_wsgi version I am currently using is 3.4

I found this link

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues

In the section "Python Patch Level Mismatch" it seems to say that I have to rebuild mod_wsgi, but this sounds somewhat difficult so wanted to ask if there is an easier fix?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You really should use your distro's package system to install these things instead of building them manually. It will make sure you get packages that work together to start with, and prevent you from breaking them later (e.g., if you later update either Apache or Python, it'll make sure `mod_wsgi` also gets updated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not complicated to build mod_wsgi.

However if you are using your distributions default python usually your distribution will package mod_wsgi such that it will already work.

Delete the mod_wsgi you uploaded to the server.

On ubuntu try:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

restart apache and then it should work.

Comment: Removing all of the mod_wsgi files was somewhat tedious, but it got the job done like you said.  At the same time, my initial install used 'apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi' and it had this issue, so this time i installed it from the source using 'wget http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz' and went through the steps in this article: [link](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/ubuntu-hardy-modwsgi-installation) under Building from the Source, and this time it worked.  mod_wsgi compiled and runtime are now the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to rebuild anything if mod_wsgi was originally linked against a Python shared library vs static. The documentation you references says that:

> This would generally not be a problem provided that both versions of
>   Python were originally installed with the '--enable-shared' option
>   supplied to 'configure'. If this option is used then the Python
>   library will be linked in dynamically at runtime and so an upgrade to
>   the Python version will be automatically used.

Since you are using system installed packages, they should be using a shared library and so there should be no issue.

You can verify by following the procedure listed at:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library